# Comparing two table IDs. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently loading two Orders and Colors tables, I wanted the Colors table to list the items that have the ID equal to Orders. For this, what occurred to me was to assign the IdOrders values ​​to a variable and compare it with my IdOrders (in my table Colors), but it is not possible to assign the database's balance to my variable

My tables:

```
public partial class Orders
{
    public int ID_Orders { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data_Registo { get; set; }
    public string Num_Encomenda { get; set; }
    public string Ref_Cliente { get; set; }
}

public partial class Colors
{
    public int ID_Orders { get; set; }
    public int ID_Programa_Malha { get; set; }
    public int ID_Linha_Cor { get; set; }
    public string Cor { get; set; }
}
```

I am working with a database already in operation and possible these tables are already used in a sql join but not how to process that information.

As I said the first thing I remembered was to do this:

My Controller:

```
var id = from d in db.Orders
         select d.ID_Orders;

        var color = db.Colors.Where(x => x.ID_Orders = id).ToList();

        var tables = new EncomendaViewModel
        {
            Orders= db.Orders.ToList(),
            Colors= color.ToList(),
        };
        return View(tables);
```

Error in **id**: *CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type to 'int'*
[image: Erro id]

Is it possible to process the data in this way?

Thanks for anyone who can help!

**-------------------(Update)------------------------------------------------**

Using **==**  *cs0019 operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type*
[image: error2]

My view in Broswer
[image: browview]

```
dbEntities sd = new dbEntities();
        List<Orders> orders= sd.Orders.ToList();
        List<Colors> colers= sd.Colors.ToList();

        var multipletable = from c in orders
                            join st in colers on c.ID_Programa equals st.ID_Programa into table1
                            from st in table1.DefaultIfEmpty()                                
                            select new MultipleClass { orders= c, colers= st  };
```

Comment: Does the error occur in this line ? db.Colors.Where(x => x.ID_Orders = id).ToList();
You need to use "==" incase you are comparing two things ->   db.Colors.Where(x => x.ID_Orders == id).ToList();

Comment: I'm using only = because if I use == it gives me an error : cs0019 operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type

Comment: `from d in db.Orders          select d.ID_Orders` returns the collection instead of single element. If you require an element then select the first (or what ever require) and do the comparison using `==`

Comment: using join I can only list the colors ordered, do not list them within the orders because I have more colors, I leave a new scheme above for those who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class OrderWithColorsViewModel
{
    public Order order { get; set; }
    public List<Colors> colers{ get; set; }
}

Public class TestOrderController : Controller
{
    public DailyMVCDemoContext db = new DailyMVCDemoContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var orders= db.Orders.ToList();
        var colers = db.Colors.ToList();
        var result = (from c in orders
                     join st in colers on c.ID_Orders equals st.id into table1
                     select new OrderWithColorsViewModel { order =c, colers = 
                     table1.ToList() }).ToList();
        return View(result);
    }
 }
```

credits: **YihuiSun**

Answer (score 2):

There could be one or more values returned from the below query.

```
var id = from d in db.Orders
         select d.ID_Orders;
```

That is the reason why it was throwing an error.
So lets try it this way

```
var color = db.Colors.Where(x => id.Contains(x.ID_Orders)).ToList();
```

Comment: so it works but list all ids, do not list ids equal to Order

Comment: In that case , you need to fix your var id = from d in db.Orders select d.ID_Orders; to return only the ID you need.

Comment: how can i return the id value of each listing?
 on top I put a picture of what is being presented to me